# V-Play generates too big APKs

Tags: android, qt, qml, v-play

I am new to V-Play. I just wanted to test it with Hello World app. My Single page app's Main.qml is 523 bytes only. But V-Play is building 20+ MB APK. Are Qt libraries that big?

Comment: The apk is essentially a zip file, open it up and see for yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behavior; the thing is that the Qt libraries are not that small.

For instance, if you develop a `QtQuick` application, you have at least `QtGui`, `QtCore`, `QtQuick` dependencies.

If the size it's a problem for you, there is an alternative: use Ministro. Ministro is an Android service that provides Qt libraries, so different apps could share the main libraries.

See [Using Ministro to Install Qt Libraries](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html#using-ministro-to-install-qt-libraries)  for more information.